# Error in installing R package "AppliedPredictiveModeling"

Tags: r

I am learning ML from *Applied Predictive Modeling* book, while installing `AppliedPredictiveModeling` package I am getting following error

```
install.packages("AppliedPredictiveModeling")
```

> Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License
>            License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

I tried looking on Google and SO to resolve this but was unable to find any solution. Please tell me how to resolve this, I have never encountered this error before. I use RStudio on Windows 7.

Comment: Does rstudio automatically install

Comment: @42- yeah it always does...I never had this error before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since no one was able to help me on this issue, I guess perhaps it was not a common problem, but I solved it finally by installing the package offline.

Answer (score 16):

I found that I was generating this error message when I mistakenly typed

```
installed.packages("Hmisc")
```

Instead of the (correct)

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
```

Comment: Ahaha I can't believe I didn't notice that! Took me ages

Comment: Same, exactly the same! Took me around 10 minutes to correct it!!

Answer (score 1):

You are mistyping `install.packages` as `installed.packages`. That's all. Just use the correct `install.packages()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when attempting to install the car package using

```
install.packages("car")
```

The response / error message I got was:

> Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests
>   Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs
>   MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

I was in the middle of an R session (RStudio, on Windows 10) when I first attempted to install it.

I fixed it by closing RStudio, and then re-running

```
install.packages("car")
```

as the first command I ran upon reopening RStudio.

Perhaps not a definitive solution, but thought it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer worked for me.

I was having the same issue with:

`install.packages('rpart.plot')`

Just restarting Rstudio did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "dependencies" method to TRUE. That helped me when installing it.